# The correct way to write 'The Morgans" on a sign?

Tags: grammaticality

How do you write "The Morgans" grammatically?

**Q:** Is it "The Morgans" or "The Morgan's"

Comment: If the last name is "Morgan," then "The Morgans" simply announces that name.  "The Morgans' " is something you might see on a welcome mat or on a placard on someone's house.  It's possessive and shows that it's their house.  "The Morgan's" is technically possible but will almost always be a mistake because when we generally don't put "the" beforehand when its singular.

Comment: The Morgans. No need to make it possessive

Comment: It depends on what's being expressed. What is the sign describing? A family? Something owned by the family? Something owned by an individual named Morgan? A group of British sports cars?